# Docker API start container returns 404

Tags: docker, docker-api

I try to control a Docker server via the Docker remote API.

Commands like

```
/containers/json?all=1
```

or

```
/containers/15999301b96f/stats
```

are working perfectly fine. But as soon as I try to start, stop or restart a container with

```
/containers/15999301b96f/start
/containers/15999301b96f/stop
/containers/15999301b96f/restart
```

I get a 404 error with the message `{"message":"page not found"}`.

I'm using docker 1.12.1 and API 1.24.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sending a GET or a POST request? [It should be POST](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/start-a-container)

Comment: It looks like this was the problem. Is was sending a GET request. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. I added this as an answer - you can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the  `/containers/(id or name)/[start|stop|restart]` endpoints you need to send POST requests instead of GET.

Reference:

- [start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24#start-a-container)
- [stop](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24#stop-a-container)
- [restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24#restart-a-container)

Answer (score 1):

From this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/get-container-stats-based-on-resource-usage), you will use `GET` request with

```
GET /containers/(id or name)/stats
```

But [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/start-a-container), to `start` or `stop`, you will use `POST` request.

```
POST /containers/(id or name)/start
POST /containers/(id or name)/stop
```